# Is this a good way to add transaction to sql ?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Is this a good way to add TRANSACTION to my code. I have to first update my code and if it fails then insert should also not work. Have a look please if it's a correct way or not. If not then please improve.

```
Begin Transaction[Transaction1]

    Begin Try

         IF(@ServiceInfoToJobStatus = 1)
            Update ServiceInfo
            Set ServiceInfoToJobStatus= 0 --To set all current jobs to prior because one person cannot have many jobs selected as current
            Where @ServiceInfoToJobStatus = 1 AND ServiceInfo.fk_PersonalInfo_ServiceInfo_PID= @fk_PersonalInfo_ServiceInfo_PID

            Set @ServiceInfoEntryDateTime= (Select GetDate())

              Insert into dbo.ServiceInfo
              (

                ServiceInfoInitialDesignation,
                ServiceInfoInitialBPS,
                fk_Districts_ServiceInfo_InitialDistrictID,
                ServiceInfoJobStatus,
                ServiceInfoFromDate,
                ServiceInfoDepartment,
                fk_PersonalInfo_ServiceInfo_PID,
                ServiceInfoServiceType  ,
                ServiceInfoOffice   ,
                ServiceInfoCadre    ,
                fk_WebUsers_ServiceInfo_UserID,
                ServiceInfoEntryDateTime,
                ServiceInfoToDesignation        ,
                ServiceInfoToBPS        ,
                fk_Districts_ServiceInfo_ToDistrictID       ,
                ServiceInfoToJobStatus      ,
                ServiceInfoToDate       ,
                ServiceInfoToDepartment     ,
                ServiceInfoToServiceType        ,
                ServiceInfoToOffice     ,
                ServiceInfoToCadre      
              )

              Values 
              (

                @ServiceInfoInitialDesignation,
                @ServiceInfoInitialBPS,
                @fk_Districts_ServiceInfo_InitialDistrictID,
                @ServiceInfoJobStatus,
                @ServiceInfoFromDate,
                @ServiceInfoDepartment,
                @fk_PersonalInfo_ServiceInfo_PID,
                @ServiceInfoServiceType ,
                @ServiceInfoOffice  ,
                @ServiceInfoCadre   ,
                @fk_WebUsers_ServiceInfo_UserID,
                Convert(varchar, @ServiceInfoEntryDateTime, 113),
                @ServiceInfoToDesignation       ,
                @ServiceInfoToBPS       ,
                @fk_Districts_ServiceInfo_ToDistrictID      ,
                @ServiceInfoToJobStatus     ,
                @ServiceInfoToDate      ,
                @ServiceInfoToDepartment        ,
                @ServiceInfoToServiceType       ,
                @ServiceInfoToOffice        ,
                @ServiceInfoToCadre     
              )

              Set @ReturnStatus = 1


    Commit Transaction[Transaction1]

    End Try

    Begin Catch

              ROLLBACK Transaction[Transaction1]

              Set @ReturnStatus= 0 
              Set @ReturnStatusMessage= (Select ERROR_MESSAGE())              

    End Catch
```

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use add `transaction (try/catch block)` if the code `updates` or `inserts` data in to the table. In your case the answer is pretty yes. But in your transaction block , there is no way to recognize whether the data `insert / update` completed.

I would use following syntax with `@@error` added.

```
BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRAN   

        //YOUR CODE

         IF @@ERROR = 0
          BEGIN
              COMMIT TRAN;
          END
 END TRY
 BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT @@ERROR AS ERROR
 ROLLBACK TRAN;
 END CATCH
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it is unclear what `update fails` means (error or no rows updated), but it does not matter much, as you can test for both pretty easy:

```
DECLARE @UpdateErrorNo INT
DECLARE @UpdateCount INT
DECLARE @InsertErrorNo INT

Begin Transaction[Transaction1]
Begin Try
    IF(@ServiceInfoToJobStatus = 1)
        Update ServiceInfo
        Set ServiceInfoToJobStatus= 0 --To set all current jobs to prior because one person cannot have many jobs selected as current
        Where @ServiceInfoToJobStatus = 1 AND ServiceInfo.fk_PersonalInfo_ServiceInfo_PID= @fk_PersonalInfo_ServiceInfo_PID

    SET @UpdateErrorNo = @@ERROR
    SET @UpdateCount = @@ROWCOUNT

    Set @ServiceInfoEntryDateTime= (Select GetDate())

    Insert into dbo.ServiceInfo
    (
        -- skipped for readability
    )

    Values 
    (
        -- skipped for readability
    )

    SET @InsertErrorNo = @@ERROR

    Set @ReturnStatus = 1

Commit Transaction[Transaction1]

End Try

Begin Catch

    ROLLBACK Transaction[Transaction1]

    Set @ReturnStatus= 0 
    Set @ReturnStatusMessage= (Select ERROR_MESSAGE())              

End Catch

-- here you can read `@UpdateErrorNo`, `@InsertErrorNo` to check for errors
```

The tricky part is that @@ERROR is set after each statement, so if you have a case like this (no try/catch):

```
BEGIN TRAN
INSERT ... -- fails
UPDATE ... -- success

-- @@ERROR will not show that it is a failure
COMMIT
```

it might lead to unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

declare @cdt datetime = getdate()
begin try
    begin transaction

```
Update dbo.ServiceInfo
Set ServiceInfoToJobStatus= 0 --To set all current jobs to prior because one person cannot have many jobs selected as current
Where @ServiceInfoToJobStatus = 1 
        AND fk_PersonalInfo_ServiceInfo_PID= @fk_PersonalInfo_ServiceInfo_PID

          Insert into dbo.ServiceInfo
          (

            ServiceInfoInitialDesignation,
            ServiceInfoInitialBPS,
            fk_Districts_ServiceInfo_InitialDistrictID,
            ServiceInfoJobStatus,
            ServiceInfoFromDate,
            ServiceInfoDepartment,
            fk_PersonalInfo_ServiceInfo_PID,
            ServiceInfoServiceType  ,
            ServiceInfoOffice   ,
            ServiceInfoCadre    ,
            fk_WebUsers_ServiceInfo_UserID,
            ServiceInfoEntryDateTime,
            ServiceInfoToDesignation        ,
            ServiceInfoToBPS        ,
            fk_Districts_ServiceInfo_ToDistrictID       ,
            ServiceInfoToJobStatus      ,
            ServiceInfoToDate       ,
            ServiceInfoToDepartment     ,
            ServiceInfoToServiceType        ,
            ServiceInfoToOffice     ,
            ServiceInfoToCadre      
          )

          Values 
          (

            @ServiceInfoInitialDesignation,
            @ServiceInfoInitialBPS,
            @fk_Districts_ServiceInfo_InitialDistrictID,
            @ServiceInfoJobStatus,
            @ServiceInfoFromDate,
            @ServiceInfoDepartment,
            @fk_PersonalInfo_ServiceInfo_PID,
            @ServiceInfoServiceType ,
            @ServiceInfoOffice  ,
            @ServiceInfoCadre   ,
            @fk_WebUsers_ServiceInfo_UserID,
            Convert(varchar, @cdt, 113),
            @ServiceInfoToDesignation       ,
            @ServiceInfoToBPS       ,
            @fk_Districts_ServiceInfo_ToDistrictID      ,
            @ServiceInfoToJobStatus     ,
            @ServiceInfoToDate      ,
            @ServiceInfoToDepartment        ,
            @ServiceInfoToServiceType       ,
            @ServiceInfoToOffice        ,
            @ServiceInfoToCadre     
          )

          return ...

commit transaction
```

end try
begin catch
    if(@@TRANCOUNT > 0)
        rollback transaction

```
return ...
```

end catch

Answer (score 0):

That's what I use:

```
Begin Try
    Begin Tran

    -- Do your thing... some DML statements

    Commit Tran
End Try

Begin Catch
    If ( @@TranCount > 0 )
        Rollback Tran
End Catch
```